# How do I consider my data as balanced or imbalanced?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to solve a multi class problem. I have 5 classes to classify. The representation of classes in the data is:

- Class_0, Count = 915841, Percentage = 10.890%
- Class_1, Count = 2419652, Percentage = 28.771%
- Class_2, Count = 1737533, Percentage = 20.660%
- Class_3, Count = 854880, Percentage = 10.165%
- Class_4, Count = 2482104, Percentage = 29.514%

Does my data is balanced or imbalanced and what technique to use for balancing?

Comment: Hi, you could also consider asking your question here [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions). Best

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's completely unrelated to programming

Comment: the answer to your question can be found at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras